# How to have turtles in Netlogo compare Variables?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

How can you have two turtles in NetLogo share and compare variables?

I need a series of turtles to compare their SN variables with their neighbors to see who has a larger value.  Right not I'm testing with agent 0 sharing the SN variable with its linked neighbors.  If the statement is true, it should set another variable (SocialST) to 1.  I can not figure out the correct syntax and I can't seem to find a good example to work from.

Should be something like this...

```
    to go
      ask HHAgent 0 [
      if [SN] of self > [SN] one-of link-neighbors [Set SocialST 1]
                    ]
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just forgetting an `of`?

```
turtles-own [SN SocialST]

to setup
  ca
  crt 25 [set SN one-of [1 2 3] setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask turtles [create-links-with n-of 5 other turtles]
end

to go
  let _aset n-of 5 turtles
  ask _aset [
    if (SN > [SN] of one-of link-neighbors) [ ;note the `of`
      set SocialST 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

Or is there something additional you wish to accomplish?  (Note that this code has the chosen turtles compare to only one of their link partners, randomly chosen.)

Comment: Note that `[SN] of self` can be simplified to just `SN`.

Comment: @SethTisue Yes, but I want the OP to focus on one change in that line.  Still ... yes, it would be better that way.  I'll edit it.

Comment: @Alan Ah ha, it was that second "of" I was missing.  Thanks for the help.